# Append value to Array inside of Rc<RefCell<Option<Vec>>>>

Tags: rust

What's the proper way to append a value to an `Option<Vec>` wrapped in an `Rc<RefCell<>>`?

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

fn main(){
    let my_vec = Some(vec![String::from("Foo"), String::from("Bar")]);
    let mut rc_vec = Rc::from(RefCell::from(my_vec));
    
    rc_vec.borrow_mut().as_ref().unwrap().push(String::from("Baz"));}
```

gives error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in a `&` reference as mutable
         rc_vec.borrow_mut().as_ref().unwrap().push(String::from("Baz"));
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Comment: You need `.as_mut()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `as_mut` instead of `as_ref`. Also you can skip the unwrap, and just map the push operation:

```rust
rc_vec
    .borrow_mut()
    .as_mut()
    .map(|v| v.push(String::from("Baz")));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5064f1bfacbfbfa5f6beff4ea766fc8f)

Comment: Note that, when `rc_vec` contains `None`, `map` skips the push operation, whereas `unwrap` panics.

Comment: @L.F., indeed, but using unwrap should have some good reason, at least it should use expect to have a cleaner error message. But that is a discussion outside of the scope of the question. thanks for pointing it out anyway :)